# How to hide keyboard with Navigation Architecture Component when cloding fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components

I have several fragments hosted in one activity. When some fragments are closed it is necessary to hide keyboard if opened, what is usually done via chaining onOptionsItemSelected from activity to fragment

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.itemId) {
        android.R.id.home -> {
            UiUtil.hideKeyboard(activity)
            return true
        }

        else -> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
    }
}
```

But it looks really bad when Navigation Architecture Component is used.
Is there any simple way to hide keyboard with Navigation Architecture Component ?

Comment: Managing the keyboard is never easy ;)

Comment: Could you post the code that looks "bad" and the code that contains the Navigation Architecture Component usage?

Comment: Can you add code?

Answer (score 10):

I want to be sure that we hide keyboard everytime when we change destination. So I do something like this:

```kotlin
class MainActivity :
        AppCompatActivity(R.layout.activity_main),
        NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener
{

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        findNavController(R.id.mainNavHostFragment).addOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        findNavController(R.id.mainNavHostFragment).removeOnDestinationChangedListener(this)
    }

    override fun onDestinationChanged(
            controller: NavController,
            destination: NavDestination,
            arguments: Bundle?
    ) {
        currentFocus?.hideKeyboard()
    }

    fun View.hideKeyboard() {
        val imm = context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0)
    }
}
```

Comment: Really nice solution 

Comment: The problem arises when we want to allow a certain destination to show the keyboard when started. The proposed solution will stop it from doing so. I went for a dirty approach with checking destination labels and only hiding the keyboard for specific screens.

Comment: @MieszkoKoźma If you want to show keyboard at certain destinations then you could just check specified ids in `onDestinationChanged()` using something like this: `if (screenIdsWithKeyboardAtStart.contains(destination.id)) showKeyboard() else hideKeyboard()`

Answer (score 0):

This should work(i`m using it in OnClickListeners usually):

```
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
```